# How to get the url when any link is clicked in Iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, url, iframe

I'm trying to retrieve any clicked URL inside an iframe without modifying the code of link. My aim is to get an URL a user clicks in iframe outside the body of an iframe. I already tried the following:

```
document.write(location.href);
document.write(window.location.href);
document.write(window.location);
document.write(document.URL);
document.write(document.location);
```

Comment: where you have wrote this , it should be in the body of pages that are  sources of your iframes

Comment: I can't modify the content that goes into iframe, is it still possible?

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById("myFrame")
.contentDocument.addEventListener("click", yourfunction, false);
```

Do not that this might only work on content from the same [domain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript).

Comment: That's the issue, content or iframe source isn't on the same domain and I'm not allowed to modify it's source.

Comment: Then, the only thing you can do to make it work is purchase the domain of which you're showing the content ;)